# Recursive equation in graph theory

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory, generating-functions, recursion, coloring

How many vertex-colorings with 3 colors has the cycle $C_n$?
How to build a recursive equation for the number of colorings over n?

I know that a cycle has either 2 or 3 colors. 2 when n is even and 3 obviously when it is odd. But what could be the recursive equation?

I believe that the sequence would be such:

$$C_0 = 0$$ 
$$C_1 = 1$$
$$C_2 = 2$$
$$C_3 = 3$$
$$C_4 = 2$$
$$C_5 = 3$$
$$ \dots $$

I have tried using `mod` over n but it didn't seem to work out. Basically, it is hard to include the base cases of $C_0$ and $C_1$ in the recursive equation to make it complete.

Comment: Arguably $C_0$ has one coloring, namely the empty map assigning colors to each of the vertices that aren't there. But that doesn't fit into the nice recurrence I end up with -- I would treat it as a degenerate case and start the recurrence at $C_1$, which has $0$ colorings. Namely, the single vertex is its own neighbor and therefore cannot have any color at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Hennings comment.

Let $f_n$ be the sequences of length $n$ with symbols $\{1,2,3\}$ starting in $1$, ending in $2$ or $3$ and not containing repeated terms.

By inspection $f(3)=2,f(4)=6$. We now find a recursion for $f_{n+2}$, we classisfy the sequences of length $n+2$ in two kinds.

First kind:

Those with second to last character equal to $2$ or $3$, there are $f_{n+1}$ sequences of this kind since a sequence with second to last character $2$ must end in $3$ and a sequence with second to last character $3$ must end in $2$.

In other words a sequence of this type is determined by the first $n+1$ terms and there are $f_{n+1}$ ways to choose these.

Second kind:

Those in which the second to last character is equal to $1$. In this case when we consider the $n$ first characters we find a sequence of length $n-2$ of the kind we are considering (since the third to last character must be different from the second to last character). There are $f_{n}$ such sequence. Once the first $n$ character have been fixed we have by hypothesis that the $n+1$'th character (the second to las character) is $1$. So we have $2$ options for the last character. It can be $2$ or $3$. Hence there are $2f_n$ sequences of this kind.

This analysis yields the recurrence $f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+2f_{n}$

---

The number of ways to color the n-gon is therefore $3f_n$ since it is possible that the sequence does not start in $1$, it may start with $2$ or $3$.

Comment: For $C_3$ and $f(3) = 2$ with $f(2)$, which has clearly $2$ possible arrangements starting with $1$: $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$. And trivially $f(1) = 1$.  I get the recurrence $f(3) = f(2) + 2f(1)$ and $2= 2 + 2$ with $1$ always starting. Where am I wrong to get such a contradiction?  Is it only for $n > 3$?

Comment: The recursion is only valid for deducing $f(5)$ and above.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** How many sequences of symbols from $\{1,2,3\}$ of length $n$ are there such that a symbol is never repeated, and the first and last symbols are different? How many are there where the first and last symbol are *equal*? Write down two mutual recurrences.